# How to scrape video URL from Webpage using python?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to download videos from a website.

Here is my code.
Every time when i run this code, it returns blank file.
Here is live code: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/19NDLYHI2n9rG6KeBCiv9vKXdwb5JL9Nb?usp=sharing

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = requests.get("https://www.mxtakatak.com/xt0.3a7ed6f84ded3c0f678638602b48bb1b840bea7edb3700d62cebcf7a400d4279/video/20000kCCF0")

page = url.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

#print(soup.prettify())

result = soup.find_all('video', class_="video-player")

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always get a blank return because `soup.find_all()` doesn't find anything.
Maybe you should check the url.content you receive by hand and then decide what to look for with `find_all()`

EDIT: After digging a bit around I found out how to get the `content_url_orig`:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json

url = requests.get("https://www.mxtakatak.com/xt0.3a7ed6f84ded3c0f678638602b48bb1b840bea7edb3700d62cebcf7a400d4279/video/20000kCCF0")

page = url.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")



result = str(soup.find_all('script')[1]) #looking for script tag inside the html-file
result = result.split('window._state = ')[1].split("</script>']")[0].split('\n')[0] 
#separating the json from the whole script-string, digged around in the file to find out how to do it

result = json.loads(result)


#navigating in the json to get the video-url
entity = list(result['entities'].items())[0][1]
download_url = entity['content_url_orig']

print(download_url)
```

Funny sidenote: If I read the [JSON](https://pastebin.com/yZD1FTzk) correctly you can find all videos with download-URLs the creator uploaded :)

Comment: You are right, showing blank means it is not find something. But why does it is not finding the data when data is there.

Comment: Digged a bit around in the sourcecode of the website and i believe you have to look for `audio` and for `content-url` to get the URL of the actual video to download

Comment: Look at this [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/jMAGNhLw), you are interested in the url in line 248

Comment: Yes, Line 248 is what I am looking for. But how to print  this URL with web scraping?

Comment: @RakeshKumar I found a working solution, edited my answer.
Would appreciate if you could accept it :))

Ah and btw: digging a lot inside the sourcecode helped a lot

Answer (score 1):

using Regex

```
import requests
import re

response = requests.get("....../video/20000kCCF0")
videoId = '20000kCCF0'
videos = re.findall(r'https://[^"]+' + videoId + '[^"]+mp4', response.text)
print(videos)
```

Comment: Wow completely forgot about regex at this point. Best idea if we just want the dowload-url.
Maybe add a `/download` to the URL after the video-id to filter the result a bit more.